# Finding the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0+} \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the following limit: $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0+} \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$$

Well I tried to do the $\exp\left(\frac{ \ln\frac{\sin x}{x}}{x^2}\right)$ then apply LHR but I seem to get to endless dervivations...

There's got to be a more simple approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) ,
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)\implies \frac{\sin x}x=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0} \left(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)\right)^{\frac1{-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)}}\right)^{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)}{x^2}}$$

Now if we set $\displaystyle -\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)=-\frac1u,$ the inner limit reduces to $\displaystyle\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1u\right)^u=e$

For the exponent,  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\left({-\frac1{3!}+O(x^2)}\right)$ as $x\ne0$ as $x\to0$

$\displaystyle\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)}=-\frac16$

Comment: Can you explain the colored part please ?  $$=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\left(1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)\right)^{\color{red}{-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)}}\right)^{\color{red}{\frac{-\frac{x^2}{3!}+O(x^4)}{x^2}}}$$

How does that equal 1/x^2 ?

Comment: @GinKin, please find the edited version

Comment: @BarryCipra, please have  a look into the edited version

Answer (score 7):

Working with $\exp\left(\frac1{x^2}\ln\frac{\sin x}x\right)$ and l'Hopital should be fine. Since $\frac{\sin x}x\to 1$ we have a "$\frac 00$" case here:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\frac{\sin x}x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac x{\sin x}\frac d{dx}\frac{\sin x}x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{{x\cos x-\sin x}}{2x^2\sin x}$$
Apply l'Hopital again and cancel one $x$
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{{x\cos x-\sin x}}{2x^2\sin x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-x\sin x}{4x\sin x+2x^2\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{4\sin x+2x\cos x}\end{align}$$
and l'Hopital again
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{4\sin x+2x\cos x} =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\cos x}{4\cos x+2\cos x-2x\sin x}=-\frac16. $$
By applying the $\exp$ again, we obtain 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac1{x^2}\ln\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=e^{-1/6}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method beased on Taylor series. Using the Taylor series of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, we get

> $$ e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(1-x^2/3!+\dots) }= e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(1-t) },$$

where $t=\frac{x^2}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{5!}+\dots$. Using the Taylor series of $\ln(1-t)$, we have

> $$e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(1-t) }=e^{\frac{1}{x^2}(-t-t^2/2-\dots) } = e^{\frac{1}{x^2}(-(x^2/3!-x^4/5!+\dots)-(x^2/3!-x^4/5!+\dots)^2/2-\dots) }\longrightarrow_{x\to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{3!}}  $$

**Note:** We used the following Taylor series

> $$ \frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\dots, $$
>
> $$ \ln(1-t)=-t-\frac{t^2}{2}- \frac{t^3}{3}-\dots\,. $$

Comment: We've only learned Taylor. Can explain more on how did you merge two series identities ?

Comment: @GinKin: I added more material.

Comment: Thanks. There should be a plus here: 

$$ e^{\frac{1}{x^2}(-x^2/3!\color{red}{+}x^4/5!-\dots) }\longrightarrow_{x\to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{3!}}  $$

So all the other $Xs$ in the series are nullified because of the limit. Very nice.

Comment: @GinKin: You are welcome.

Comment: Wait I think there's a problem with the signs. the $-t$ in the $\ln$ will flip all the signs of the other series so it should be: $$e^{\frac{1}{x^2}(\color{red}{+}x^2/3!\color{red}{-}x^4/5!\color{red}{+}\dots) }\longrightarrow_{x\to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{3!}}$$

Comment: @GinKin: It is ok now.

Comment: I see what you did there. BTW, how do you get rid of the $1$ from the sinx series ?

Comment: @GinKin: $\ln(1-t)=-t-t^2/2-\dots \implies \ln(1-t)= -(x^2/3!-\dots)-(x^2/3!-\dots)^2/2-\dots,$ since $t=x^2/3!-\dots$.

Comment: Yes but what about that one: $$\frac{\sin t}{t}=\color{red}{1}-\frac{t^2}{3!}+\dots,$$ why you can "get rid" of it when defining $t$ ?

Comment: @GinKin: Get rid of what?

Comment: I pressed enter before finishing the sentence, see the edit.

Comment: @GinKin: Just follow my answer step by step.

Comment: I really do follow it step by step. You defined $t$ to be sinx/x series so what happened to the $1$ I colored above ?

Comment: Can you clarify that $t$ please ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{\frac1{x^2}} =e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}= e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\sin x-x)'}{(x^3)'}}=$$$$= e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}}= e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\cos x-1)'}{(3x^2)'}}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin x}{6x}}=e^{\frac{-1}{6}}. $$

I used a "shortcut" for $1^{\infty}$ and applied the rule of L'Hospital twice.

"Shortcut":

If

$\lim_{x→α}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x→α}g(x)= \infty $

then $$\lim_{x→α}(f(x))^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}(1+f(x)−1)^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}[[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{(f(x)-1)}]^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}= e^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}.$$

Comment: Did you not forget a log on second equality?

Comment: What is that shortcut ?

Comment: @GinKin. This shortcut (exposed in my answer) turn power limit of a function in the limit of a product functions. As you can see it is very useful in this situation, especially for those who are not familiar with Taylor's formula or with other non elementary-secondary school students.

Comment: @GinKin. It can be easily noticed due to the elegance and aesthetics calculations using this shortcut.

Comment: First line: shouldn't there be a log in the exponent ? also why is it sinx-x ? Lastly, can you explain that last move: $$\lim_{x→α}[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}= e^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}.$$

Comment: $\lim_{x→α}[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]=\lim_{u(x)→0}[(1+u(x))^{\frac{1}{u(x)}}]=e$.This is a well known limit related to the number $e$.

Comment: And other users of the site using this shortcut.  See first answer here:math.stackexchange.com/questions/299801/evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-left1-frac-ln-xfx-right-displaystyle-frac?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

### Easy trick

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (\frac{\sin x}{x})^{\frac1{x^2}}  =\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x -x}{x}+1\right)\right) \sim \lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{6}\frac{\ln\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)}{\frac{x^2}{6}}\right)= \exp(-\frac16)$$

Given that $$\sin x -x \sim -\frac{x^3}{6}~~~~and ~~~~ \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1-u\right)}{u} = -1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0+} \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$$

$$f(x):=\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$$

$$\ln f(x)= \dfrac{1}{x^2}\ln \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1+1\right)$$

$$\ln f(x)=\dfrac{\ln \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1+1\right)}{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1}\times \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1}{x^2}$$

$$\ln f(x)=\dfrac{\ln \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1+1\right)}{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1}\times \dfrac{\sin x-x}{x^3}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\cancelto{1}{\dfrac{\ln \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1+1\right)}{\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1}}\times \cancelto{\dfrac{-1}{6}}{\dfrac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}=\dfrac{-1}{6}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=\text{exp}(-\dfrac{1}{6})$$

---

**Used from**

[Calculate the limit : $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}$ WITHOUT using L'Hopital's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077619/calculate-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-fracx-sinxx3-without-using-lhopi)

[Limit of a function without using L'Hôpital Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748226/limit-of-a-function-without-using-lh%C3%B4pital-rule)