# Limit of $\sqrt[x]{\frac{\tan x}{x}}$ as $x \to 0$

Tags: limits

I am trying to calculate the Limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[x]{\frac{\tan x}{x}}$$

[Wolfram Alpha says it's $1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%20-%3E%200%20of%20%28tan%28x%29/x%29%5E%281/x%29). But I get

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[x]{\frac{\tan x}{x}}$$
$$= \exp \lim_{x \to 0} \ln \left(\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{1/x}\right)$$
$$= \exp \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(\tan(x)) - \ln(x)}{x}$$
Using L'Hospital:
$$= \exp \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{\tan(x)\cos^2(x)} - \frac{1}{x}}{1}$$
$$= \exp \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} - \frac{1}{x}$$
$$= \exp \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} - \frac{1}{x}$$
$$= \exp \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin(2x)}{\sin(2x) x}$$

But when I calculate
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x - \sin(2x)}{\sin(2x) x}$$ [with Wolfram Alpha I get $\pm \infty$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+-%3E+0+of+%28x-sin%282x%29%29%2F%28x%2asin%282x%29%29) . So the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt[x]{\frac{\tan x}{x}}$ should be $e^{\pm \infty} = 0 \text{ or } \infty \neq 1$. Which is both wrong.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: $\sin x\cos x\ne\cos (2x)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Using your argument, $(\tan x / x)^{1/x^2}$ should go to $1$ for $x \to 0$ as well. But it's $\sqrt[3]{e}$. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+-%3E+0+of+%28tan%28x%29%2Fx%29%5E%281%2Fx%5E2%29

Comment: Oops, sorry.${}$

Comment: The power in my first example is $1/x$, in my second it's $1/x^2$. None of theam head to zero for $x \to 0$.

Comment: Claude Leibovici's solution is quite neat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin x \cos x = \frac{\sin 2x}{2}$, instead of just $\sin 2x$

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Taylor expansions
$$\tan (x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+ ...$$
$$\frac{\tan (x)}{x}=1+\frac{x^2}{3}+ ...$$
$$\left(\frac{\tan (x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=1+\frac{x}{3}+ ... $$

Comment: Could you explain how you raised both sides to $\dfrac {1}{x}$ ?

Comment: @Apurv. Binomial theorem

Comment: Oh! this is smart... Taking the limit at 1 would make all $x$'s vanish and we'll be left with $1$. Elegant...+1

Comment: @Apurv. Thank you. I must confess that I am a fanatic lover of Taylor expansions (starting 55 years ago!). Cheers.

Comment: Using your method, what is $\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x \to 0$?

Comment: This is a very good point ! It DOES NOT work but the series would be $\sqrt[3]{e}+\frac{7}{90} \sqrt[3]{e} x^2+ ...$. (so, +1 for your question and smart remark) ! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is the limit to be evaluated then we have $$\begin{aligned}\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt[x]{\frac{\tan x}{x}}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\log\left(\sqrt[x]{\frac{\tan x}{x}}\right)\text{ (by continuity of }\log)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{\tan x}{x}\right)}{x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{\tan x}{x} - 1\right)}{\dfrac{\tan x}{x} - 1}\cdot\dfrac{\dfrac{\tan x}{x} - 1}{x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}1\cdot\frac{\tan x - x}{x^{2}}\text{ (because }y = \frac{\tan x}{x} - 1 \to 0\text{ and }\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + y)}{y} = 1)\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^{2}\cos x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^{2}\cdot 1}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x}{x^{2}} + x\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}\\
&= 0 + 0\cdot \frac{1}{2} = 0\end{aligned}$$ The first limit is [calculated here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/635207/72031) without any series expansion or LHR and the second limit is pretty standard based on $1 - \cos x = 2\sin^{2}(x/2)$ and using $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x }{x} = 1$. It follows that $L = e^{0} = 1$.

**Update**: It is also possible to use the approach of the linked answer above to calculate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x - x}{x^{2}}$$ Clearly if $0 < x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then we have $\sin x < x < \tan x$ so that $$0 < \frac{\tan x - x}{x^{2}} < \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^{2}} = \tan x\cdot\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}}$$ Taking limits as $x \to 0^{+}$ and using Squeeze Theorem we get $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\tan x - x}{x^{2}} = 0$$ And to handle $x \to 0^{-}$ we can put $ x = -y$ and get the left hand limit also as $0$.