# This is a problem from Differential Calculus for Beginners by Joseph Edwards

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
I attempted to expand $\sin x$ and am unsure how to proceed.
$$1-\frac{x}{3!}\left[x^2-\frac{x^4}{5\times 4} \cdots \right]$$

Can anyone please help me with this Problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a limit in an efficent way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635195/find-a-limit-in-an-efficent-way) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Crightarrow%200%5E%2B%7D(%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%20x%7D%7Bx%7D)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%24&p=1). There's also other duplicates, e.g., [Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$](/q/2127280).

Comment: Note that all $4$ answers of the proposed duplicate, and all but one [answer](/a/2127303) among the $5$ of the other linked question, use techniques other than [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) (based on your implied request using the "limits-without-lhopital" tag). Also, both questions only deal with $x\to 0^{+}$, but you can use that result to get what the limit for $x\to 0^{-}$ would be. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: If you're interested in more examples like this, see the 2nd half of [this 28 December 2007 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/qNtFFGFhJcc/m/TMxvaEdO8IoJ). In case anyone is wondering why the OP's limit isn't one of the 24 numbered limit examples I gave, that's because the OP's limit was one of 3 or 4 such limits (exponential indeterminate forms) that were carefully worked out before I listed those additional 24 limits for students to practice on, this being in the handout of mine (written back in the late 1990s) that I copied those 24 examples from.

Answer (score 1):

Write it in e to the power ln format . Then u get 1/x(Ln(sin/x)) then put limit for sin/x. I think u got the idea

Comment: This needs work to be an actual answer. It’s fine (although hard to decipher) as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{\sin(x)}{x})^{1/x}$.

A nice property of logarithms is that they can bring an exponent within a function in front. Because of this, we have $$\ln(f(x)) = \frac{\ln(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x})}{x}$$


We know from the squeeze theorem that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$ Thus, we have $$\ln(f(x)) = \frac{\ln(1)}{x}$$


$\ln(1) = 0$, so we have $$\ln(f(x)) = \frac{0}{x} = 0$$
Following this, we know that $$\ln(f(x)) = 0$$ so we take both sides to the power of e: $$e^{\ln(f(x))} = e^0$$ $$f(x) = 1$$

Comment: The formula for $f(x)$ does not make sense, as the right hand side does not depend on $x.$ If you consider the limit of $\left ({\sin x\over x}\right )^{1/x^2}$ your method will give a false result.