# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to0}(x+e^{2x})^{\frac2 x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}(x+e^{2x})^{\frac2 x}$$
I saw somewhere that they put all the expression as the power of e with ln but I can't figure why.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{2x}-1}x=2$, so

$$\lim_{x\to0}(x+e^{2x})^{\frac2 x}=\lim_{x\to0}(1+(x+e^{2x}-1))^{\frac1{x+e^{2x}-1}(2+\frac{2(e^{2x}-1)}x)}=e^6 $$

Comment: Bring it to *the* form like you just don't care :)

Answer (score 0):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632527/finding-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-0-left-frac-sin-xx-right1-x/632536#632536). Here is an approach
$$ e^{2/x\ln(x+e^{2x})}= e^{2/x(3x-5/2x^2+\dots)} \longrightarrow_{x\to 0} e^6.$$

**Note:** We used the Taylor series

> $$\ln(x+e^{2x})= 3\,x-{\frac {5}{2}}{x}^{2}+O \left( {x}^{3} \right)   $$.