# Limit of a function without using L'Hôpital Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$$

without using L'Hôpital Rule.

Comment: That will be hard to do.

Comment: @DavidMitra especially because it's wrong. The limit is $0$. $ln(x) = o(x)$

Comment: I can help you if the question is proving $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = 1.$$

Comment: I suppose that your question contains a typo. Would it be $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$$

Comment: not sure, but the question given to me is infinity and if u use lopital rule it does give 1

Comment: Are you sure you know how to use l'hôspital rule ? $1/x$ goes to 0 when $x$ goes to $+\infty$

Comment: ok then what about the case when x tends to 0?

Comment: If you mean @Tunk-Fey limit then calculate $\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{1}{(y+1)}}dy$. Now get an upper and lower bound for this integral (think about areas) and go from there.

Comment: Which definition of the logarithm are you working with?

Comment: I agree with Daniel Fischer. Your question is clearly dependent on how you define the logarithm (hence, what properties of the logarithm are assumed). That is because your question is a basic property of the logarithm (which, in terms of derivatives, is the derivative of $\log(1+x)$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

This is just the derivative of $y=lnx$ at $x=1$ by using the classic definition of the derivative. And so the answer is $1$. In this way, L'Hospital is avoided.

Comment: Good idea, but there is some whiff of circularity.

Comment: Not really, only a whiff of ambiguity since we don't know how the OP defines log.

Answer (score 2):

If you define $\log(1+x)$ as the integral of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and you don't want to use the fundamental theorem of calculus either, you could bound $\frac{1}{1+x}$ between $1-\epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$ for sufficiently small $x$, and use this to get the required limit.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT :**

If that limit you are asking, then you can use [Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) for $\ln(1+x)$ to prove $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1.$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: I believe if he can use McLaurin series he would not bother with avoiding l'Hôspital Rule and just go straight for an equivalent

Comment: @T_O I just try to give a hint in case he didn't know.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey You beat me to it.

Comment: @T_O I don't necessarily think he wouldn't know about Taylor series. Some calc books don't mention l'Hospital until doing sequences and series.

Comment: Why on earth are you putting a huge "Q.E.D." after something that is a _hint_ not a proof?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry if my Q.E.D. sign is bothering you. I put it behind of every my answer, even if only a hint, just as my signature. It's kind of a personal touch. I hope you don't mind. **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Integrate $\frac{1}{1+y}$ between 0 and x. Look at the picture below to get an upper and lower bound for this integral. Divide through by x and take the limit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This limit is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1,
$$
which is easily handled with the definition
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}.
$$
As noticed above, it all boils down to your definition of the exponential or the logarithmic function.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x>0$ We have 
$$\frac{x}{x+1} =\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{x+1} \le \int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{t+1} =\color{red}{\ln(x+1 )}=\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{t+1}  \le \int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{1}  = x $$

that is for $x>0$

$$\frac{x}{x+1} \le \ln(x+1 ) \le   x \implies\color{red}{\frac{1}{x+1}\le  \frac{\ln(x+1 )}{x} \le 1}$$
$$\color{red}{1=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x+1}\le  \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+1 )}{x} \le 1}$$

that $$\color{blue}{  \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+1 )}{x} = 1}$$

By Squeeze Theorem, we have,