# 1 to the infinity indeterminate limit

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$ then show that $$\lim_{x\to a}\{f(x)\}^{g(x)}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to a}{g(x)\{f(x)-1\}}}.$$
I started off as:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\{f(x)\}^{g(x)} = e^{\lim\limits_{x\to a}{g(x)\{\ln f(x)\}}}$$
$$=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\{\ln f(x)\}\over {\frac{1}{g(x)}}}}$$
$$=e^{-\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.\frac{\{g(x)\}^2}{f(x)}}}.$$

But this doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left[1+\frac1{\frac1{f(x)-1}}\right]^{g(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left[1+\frac1{\frac1{f(x)-1}}\right]^{\frac1{f(x)-1} \cdot(f(x)-1)g(x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} e^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}\phantom{\frac1{\frac1n}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Latex issue: Does anyone know how to make the lines to be more separate? vspace doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `\phantom{blah}` produces a blank area of the same size as its argument would take up if typeset. Normally, that's used for horizontal alignment but I used it in your example to give a bit more vertical space.

Comment: Actually, `\vphantom` would have been a better way but, hey, `\phantom` worked.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** use $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$.

Then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \ln f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \left( \frac{\ln (1+[f(x)-1])}{f(x)-1}\cdot[f(x)-1] \right)=...?$

Answer (score 0):

If

$\lim_{x→α}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x→α}g(x)= \infty $

then $$\lim_{x→α}(f(x))^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}(1+f(x)−1)^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}[[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{(f(x)-1)}]^{g(x)}= \lim_{x→α}[(1+f(x)−1)^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}= e^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)-1)g(x)}.$$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632527/finding-the-limit-displaystyle-lim-x-to-0-left-frac-sin-xx-right1-x/632541#632541